# I need to write a query to return user_type based on all types that user was associated to in a single row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table with a *user* column and *user_type* column. A user can be associated to multiple user_type's.

There are a total of five different user_type's in the column. I have a requirement to find each user who is associated with all the user_type's.

For example:

```
User_type       User
--------------------
Teacher         AAAA
Principal       AAAA
Employee        AAAA
Admin           BBBB
Cashier         CCCC
Teacher         DDDD
Principal       DDDD
Employee        DDDD
Admin           EEEE
Cashier         EEEE
```

Suppose this is the table (this is just a sample table). Here AAAA needs to be declared as UT_NEW1 
BBBB as UT_NEW2 
CCCC as UT_NEW3 
DDDD again as UT_NEW1 
and EEEE as UT_NEW4.

We cannot use count in this case as it cannot be determined that if a particular user has three user_type's, and then they can be declared as a particular group.

I am trying to do:

If User = 'Some user' and his user_type = ('user_type1' and 'user_type2' and 'user_type3') then he/she can be declared as 'type1'.

A user belongs to a group defined by particular user_types. Only if a user have those particular user_types and none other, can they be declared to belong to the group.

Comment: You write "There are total of 5 different user_type in the column", but there are 6 in your example table. Also, can you elaborate on you mean by "associated with all the user_type"? There doesn't seem to be a user that is associated with all 6 user_type in your example. Do you mean that a contractor must be both a "Cashier" and a "Distributor"? So that a user that is both a "Teacher" and a "Cashier", but nothing else, cannot be classified?

Comment: basically, what i mean to say is that if one user is associated with more that one user_type then he can be given a designation for that. For instance BBBB in my example above can also be  of user_type 'Teacher' and he/she is called as a 'Worker'

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. Do you mean that a Worker just have 2, any 2, user types? It doesn't matter which? Please note that any explanation to how your logic is suppose to work needs to go into your Question. Not into comments here or on Answers. Use the edit option on your post :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. updated the post :)

Comment: I see :) It's still a little confusing though. This is my understanding. A user belongs to a group defined by particular user_types.Only if a user have those particular user_types and none other, can be be declared to belong to the group. Is this what you mean? Your edit could be interpreted as the "UT_NEW1" are not set in stone, but just on the fly groups.. is that what you mean to say? (Note: your old names were easier to understand :)

Comment: Yes that is what exactly i am trying to ask. :)

Comment: Ok. You can take my comment and put it into your Question, but since you have two Answers already, I think it would be better if you changed the naming of your user_type back :)

Comment: Oh. I am doing so many edits.

Comment: Thank you so much for reviewing my post. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a user "PPPP" and created the table. I changed the column name to `usr`, since Oracle is a little picky about using keyword as columns:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
    usr_type VARCHAR(30),
    usr      VARCHAR(30)
);
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO users(usr_type,usr) VALUES ('Teacher',   'AAAA');
  INSERT INTO users(usr_type,usr) VALUES ('Principal', 'AAAA');
  INSERT INTO users(usr_type,usr) VALUES ('Employee',  'AAAA');
  INSERT INTO users(usr_type,usr) VALUES ('Admin',     'BBBB');
  INSERT INTO users(usr_type,usr) VALUES ('Cashier',   'CCCC'); -- CCCC doesn't belong to any group
  INSERT INTO users(usr_type,usr) VALUES ('Teacher',   'DDDD');
  INSERT INTO users(usr_type,usr) VALUES ('Principal', 'DDDD');
  INSERT INTO users(usr_type,usr) VALUES ('Employee',  'DDDD');
  INSERT INTO users(usr_type,usr) VALUES ('Admin',     'EEEE'); -- <-- this is the initial focus 
  INSERT INTO users(usr_type,usr) VALUES ('Cashier',   'EEEE'); -- <-- this is the initial focus
  INSERT INTO users(usr_type,usr) VALUES ('Admin',     'PPPP'); -- PPPP doesn't belong to any group
  INSERT INTO users(usr_type,usr) VALUES ('Employee',  'PPPP'); -- PPPP doesn't belong to any group
END;
/
```

Since this is a database, I decided to add a table holding the groups (you've also called them types):

```
CREATE TABLE groups(
    usr_type VARCHAR(30),
    group_no VARCHAR(30)
);
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO groups(usr_type,group_no) VALUES ('Teacher',   'Group1');
  INSERT INTO groups(usr_type,group_no) VALUES ('Principal', 'Group1');
  INSERT INTO groups(usr_type,group_no) VALUES ('Employee',  'Group1');
  INSERT INTO groups(usr_type,group_no) VALUES ('Admin',     'Group2');
  INSERT INTO groups(usr_type,group_no) VALUES ('Admin',     'Group3');
  INSERT INTO groups(usr_type,group_no) VALUES ('Cashier',   'Group3');
  INSERT INTO groups(usr_type,group_no) VALUES ('Admin',     'Group4'); -- no users in Group4
  INSERT INTO groups(usr_type,group_no) VALUES ('Cashier',   'Group4'); -- no users in Group4
  INSERT INTO groups(usr_type,group_no) VALUES ('Astronaut', 'Group4'); -- no users in Group4
END;
/
```

I picked user "EEEE" and made a simple join:

```
SELECT *
  FROM users  u
  JOIN groups g ON u.usr_type = g.usr_type
 WHERE usr = 'EEEE';

+----------+------+----------+----------+
| USR_TYPE | USR  | USR_TYPE | GROUP_NO |
+----------+------+----------+----------+
| Admin    | EEEE | Admin    | Group2   |
+----------+------+----------+----------+
| Admin    | EEEE | Admin    | Group3   |
+----------+------+----------+----------+
| Cashier  | EEEE | Cashier  | Group3   |
+----------+------+----------+----------+
| Admin    | EEEE | Admin    | Group4   |
+----------+------+----------+----------+
| Cashier  | EEEE | Cashier  | Group4   |
+----------+------+----------+----------+
```

User "EEEE" belongs to Group3 only. Not Group2, since "EEEE" has both user_type "Admin" and "Cashier", and also not Group4, since Group4 also has the additional "Astronaut".

First, I just made a simple group by:

```
SELECT g.group_no, count(g.usr_type)
  FROM users  u
  JOIN groups g ON u.usr_type = g.usr_type
 WHERE usr = 'EEEE'
 GROUP BY g.group_no;

+----------+-------------------+
| GROUP_NO | COUNT(G.USR_TYPE) |
+----------+-------------------+
| Group4   |                 2 |
+----------+-------------------+
| Group2   |                 1 |
+----------+-------------------+
| Group3   |                 2 |
+----------+-------------------+
```

Then I added the condition that the count has to be indentical to the count of the same group_no in the groups table, so if there are 3 rows with Group4 in the groups table, there also have to be 3 rows in the join. But since there are only 2 rows in the join, but 3 rows in the groups table for Group4, that row is now gone:

```
SELECT g.group_no, count(g.usr_type)
  FROM users  u
  JOIN groups g ON u.usr_type = g.usr_type
 WHERE usr = 'EEEE'
 GROUP BY g.group_no
HAVING count(g.usr_type) = (SELECT count(1)
                              FROM groups g2
                             WHERE g.group_no = g2.group_no);

+----------+-------------------+
| GROUP_NO | COUNT(G.USR_TYPE) |
+----------+-------------------+
| Group2   |                 1 |
+----------+-------------------+
| Group3   |                 2 |
+----------+-------------------+
```

Then I added a similar condition for the users table. If there are 2 users in the users table, then the count in the join has to also be 2. Since there are 2 rows with "EEEE" in the users table, but only a count of 1 in the join, Group2 is now also gone:

```
SELECT g.group_no
  FROM users  u
  JOIN groups g ON u.usr_type = g.usr_type
 WHERE 1 = 1  -- always true
   AND usr = 'EEEE'
 GROUP BY g.group_no, u.usr
HAVING count(g.usr_type) = (SELECT count(1)
                              FROM groups g2
                             WHERE g.group_no = g2.group_no)
   AND count(g.usr_type) = (SELECT count(1)
                              FROM users u2
                             WHERE u.usr = u2.usr);

+----------+
| GROUP_NO |
+----------+
| Group3   |
+----------+
```

So we end up with having 'EEEE' belong to group3 :) Note: I also removed selecting the actual `count(g.usr_type)`, since it's irrevant now.

Removing the query conditition for only "EEEE" gets the group for all users:

```
SELECT u.usr, g.group_no
  FROM users  u
  JOIN groups g ON u.usr_type = g.usr_type
 WHERE 1 = 1  -- always true
 GROUP BY g.group_no, u.usr
HAVING count(g.usr_type) = (SELECT count(1)
                              FROM groups g2
                             WHERE g.group_no = g2.group_no)
   AND count(g.usr_type) = (SELECT count(1)
                              FROM users u2
                             WHERE u.usr = u2.usr);

+------+----------+
| USR  | GROUP_NO |
+------+----------+
| AAAA | Group1   |
+------+----------+
| BBBB | Group2   |
+------+----------+
| DDDD | Group1   |
+------+----------+
| EEEE | Group3   |
+------+----------+
```

It's also available at [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=97bc2bc0b0014edbbc5fe98e68e71d76), if you want to play with it.

Answer (score 0):

You have total of 5 user types so you can find the user who is associated with all the user type using `GROUP BY` and having as follows:

```
select user, 
       case when cnt = 3 then 'Owner' 
            when cnt = 2 then 'Worker' 
            when cnt = 1 then 'Contractor' 
       end as user_type_new 
  from (select user, count(distinct user_type) as cnt
          from your_table
       group by user)
```

Comment: i cannot use count clause, i need to pass the user_type as based on that i will need to identify if he is an 'owner', or contractor etc

Comment: So, what i mean is,
if ((AAAA == Teacher) && (AAAA == Principal) && (AAAA == Employee))
then AAAA is Owner.

Count cannot be used becase there can be a user who can be in 3 different user_type but he/she cannot be an Owner, rather he/she needs to be identified as someone else

Answer (score 0):

> I have a requirement to find each user who is associated with all the user_type.

You can use aggregation:

```
select user
from user_types;
group by user
having count(*) = (select count(distinct user_type) from user_types);
```

If you know there are 5, then:

```
select user
from user_types;
group by user
having count(*) = 5;
```

If there are three specific items, then you can use:

```
select user
from user_types
where user_type in ('user_type1', 'user_type2', 'user_type3')
group by user
having count(*) = 3;
```

(This obviously generalizes to any number of elements.)

And if you want to insert these back into the table, you you can use `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into user_types (user, user_type)
    select user, 'owner'
    from user_types
    group by user
    having count(*) = 5;
```

Comment: i cannot use count clause, i need to pass the user_type as based on that i will need to identify if he is an 'owner', or admin etc

Comment: @User9123 . . . That is not the question you asked.  However, I edited the answer for what you seem to want.